# Python | NameError when importing a class into a test script

Tags: python, class, module, nameerror

so I have a Python module (time.py) which defines "class Time". Then I have a test script (test_time.py) which imports the class, but when I try to create an instance of the class, it throws a NameError. *But if I change the module's name to time1.py the test script works fine.* I just can't figure out why it won't work when the module is named *time.py*. Thanks in advance.

**time.py:**

```
class Time:
    def __init__(self, init_hr = 12, init_min = 0, init_ampm = "AM"):
        self.hr = init_hr
        self.min = init_min
        self.ampm = init_ampm
    def ..... etc.
```

**test_time.py:**

```
from time import *
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = Time()
    t2 = ...... etc.
```

**The error I get when I run *test_time.py:***

NameError: name 'Time' is not defined

Comment: There is a module `time` in the standard library which you have accidentally imported.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't think about that, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because time is a module of the standard library too but it contains no Time object. 
If you try to get the module directory that is imported with:

```
import time
print(time.__file__)
```

you'll get an error like:

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__file__'
```

If you rename time.py to time1.py this mismatch is resolved and the test script use your local module.

```
import time1
print(time1.__file__)
```

then you get:

```
/<path-to-your-directory>/time1.pyc
```

If you specify what you want to import from each module you can avoid such mismatchs, as it would give you an error immediatedly:

```
from time import Time
```

you get:

```
ImportError: cannot import name Time
```

and also rename your importing-from modules with more "complex" names in order to avoid such mismatches is a good practice.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the response, I'll definitely make the file names more meaningful to avoid this in the future

Answer (score 0):

As Klaus D. already replied, python already has a time module. Python import resolution dictates that when you do `import time`, python checks if there is a globally installed module in Python(inside Python core or installed with pip) called `time`.So I suggest you change your file name as you said to `time1.py` or something else.

Comment:  I appreciate the response